# Assume content-type of JSON in Spring MVC controller

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a Spring 3.1 Controller method similar to this

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void (@RequestBody SomeObject obj) {
    // Do something
}
```

The spring configuration file is setup properly to accept JSON. If I send a request with Content Type set to "application/json" and send in the proper body in JSON, everything works as its supposed to.

If I do not specify Content Type to be "application/json" then a HTTP 415 is returned which is also expected based upon the configuration. Is there anyway to tell Spring to always treat the RequestBody as if it is JSON regardless of the Content Type?

Comment: Don't thnk so. From the docs: MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter (or MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter with Jackson 1.x)
An HttpMessageConverter implementation that can read and write JSON using Jackson's ObjectMapper. JSON mapping can be customized as needed through the use of Jackson's provided annotations. When further control is needed, a custom ObjectMapper can be injected through the ObjectMapper property for cases where custom JSON serializers/deserializers need to be provided for specific types. By default this converter supports (application/json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process the `@RequestBody` annotated parameter and inject an argument, Spring uses `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`. The first thing this `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` does is check the `Content-Type` header. If it's missing it defaults to `application/octet-stream`. It then gets the list of registered `HttpMessageConverter` instances. By default, these are

```
StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
stringConverter.setWriteAcceptCharset(false);

messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter()); // if your argument is a byte[]
messageConverters.add(stringConverter); // if your argument is a String
messageConverters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter()); // if your argument is a Resource
messageConverters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter<Source>()); // if your argument is one of the javax.xml Source classes
messageConverters.add(new AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter());  // for application/x-www-form-urlencoded content-type
if (romePresent) {
    messageConverters.add(new AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter()); // for application/atom+xml content-type
    messageConverters.add(new RssChannelHttpMessageConverter()); // for application/rss+xml content-type
}
if (jaxb2Present) {
    messageConverters.add(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter()); // if your argument class is annotated with @XmlRootElement or @XmlType
}
if (jackson2Present) {
    messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()); // for content-type application/json and application/*+json (wildcard json)
}
else if (jacksonPresent) {
    messageConverters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter()); // in case, but rarely, same as above
}
```

The `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` then iterates over this list, in order, and calls `canRead()` on each `HttpMessageConverter`. If it returns `true`, The `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` uses that `HttpMessageConverter` to create the argument. If it never finds one, it throws an `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException` which makes the `DispatcherServlet` send a 415 response.

With the above defaults, it is not possible. You would have to create and register your own `HttpMessageConverter` that can do this. Note that it would apply to all your handler methods with `@RequestBody` annotated parameters.

---

As a suggestion, the `Content-Type` header is specifically used for this scenario, you should use it.

Comment: I was able to suggest that we levy the requirement to our clients that they set the Content-Type header correctly.